# How do I check data type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, interpreter

I'm trying to write a brainfuck interpreter in Haskell as an exercise/fun project, and I've run into a little problem.

Brainfuck's "while loop" structure is just a series of commands stuck inside of brackets. I'm trying to build up the syntax tree in a way that I store operators inside loops inside of the `[` data constructor.

This is how the data declaration for the commands and syntax "tree" look at the moment:

```
data Operator = Plus
                | Minus
                | RShift 
                | LShift
                | Dot
                | Comma
                | SBracket [Operator]
                | EBracket
                deriving (Show, Eq)


type STree = [Operator]
```

What I'm trying to do is take a `String` of commands like `"+><[.>]"` and parse it into an `STree` that looks like this:

```
[Plus, RShift, LShift, SBracket [Dot, RShift], EBracket]
```

So far, I'm only able to get a one-dimensional list out of the `String`, because I'm not sure how to check if the head of the list is a `SBracket` in order to put new operators in it's operator list instead of at the head of the main list.

Here's the function I'm using to do the parsing:

```
matchChar :: Char -> Maybe Operator
matchChar c = case c of 
                '+' -> Just Plus
                '-' -> Just Minus
                '>' -> Just RShift  
                '<' -> Just LShift
                '.' -> Just Dot
                ',' -> Just Comma
                '[' -> Just (SBracket [])
                ']' -> Just EBracket
                _   -> Nothing

getChars :: [Char] -> STree
getChars str = foldr toOp [] str
    where 
            toOp x acc = case matchChar x of
                            Just a -> a:acc
                            Nothing -> acc
```

What I'd like to be able to do is check if `head acc` is an `SBracket` instance, and if so, instead of prepending the new `Operator` to the list, prepend it to `SBracket`'s `Operator` list.

I've tried pattern matching (`toOp x ((SBracket list):xs) = ...`) as well as trying to *explicitly* check the head of the list (`if head acc == SBracket ...`), but neither of these things work properly.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I'd redefine `SBracket [Operator]` as just `Bracket STree` and get rid of `EBracket`. Then I'd change your parser to keep track of both the "current STree" as well as a list of parents. Every time you encounter a bracket, you push the current tree onto your parent list and create a new tree. And when you encounter an end bracket, you take your current tree, wrap it with the `Bracket` constructor, pop off your first parent, add the bracket to the end of that and make that your current tree.

---

Here's a wholly untested (don't have ghc on this comp) version that may or may not work:

```
data Operator = Plus
                | Minus
                | RShift
                | LShift
                | Dot
                | Comma
                | Bracket [Operator]
                deriving (Show, Eq)

parse :: [Char] -> Either String [Operator]
parse str = parse' str [] []
  where parse' :: [Char] -> [Operator] -> [[Operator]] -> Either String [Operator]
        parse' [] context [] = Right (reverse context)
        parse' [] context _ = Left "unclosed []"
        parse' (']':cs) _ [] = Left "unexpected ]"
        parse' (c:cs) ctx stack
            | c == '+' = parse' cs (Plus:ctx) stack
            | c == '-' = parse' cs (Minus:ctx) stack
            | c == '>' = parse' cs (RShift:ctx) stack
            | c == '<' = parse' cs (LShift:ctx) stack
            | c == '.' = parse' cs (Dot:ctx) stack
            | c == ',' = parse' cs (Comma:ctx) stack
            | c == '[' = parse' cs [] (ctx:stack)
            | c == ']' = parse' cs (Bracket (reverse ctx):s) tack
            | otherwise = parse' cs ctx stack
          where (s:tack) = stack
```

Comment: (A case statement mapping and a function mapping `+-<>.,` to `Plus`,`Minus` etc, might be nicer than the chain of guards :) )

Comment: @dbaupp: Such a function wouldn't be able to handle '[' and ']' since those are special. And using a case felt like it was going too far off the right edge.

Comment: This did work after a few modifications (`where` needs to be after all of the guards, guards use the form `|Bool = (...)` instead of `|Bool -> (...)`, and `context` in the second to last guard statement needs to be `ctx`). I'm going to break this down so I can understand what's happening a little better, but thank you for your help!

Comment: @BenjaminKovach: I just made the changes you said. Is it correct now?

Comment: @Tinctorius Yeah, I made that change too :)

Comment: @Tinctorius: Is [this](https://gist.github.com/3102666) what you mean about the case patterns?

Comment: @BenjaminKovach: Hrm, I'm actually surprised this works. The `(s:tack) = stack` binding should be done lazily, shouldn't it?

Comment: @KevinBallard You mean, you would expect `s:tack` to be `(reverse ctx):s:tack`, making `tack` map to `s:tack` and duplicating the current first list of Operations? I'm not sure -- I wonder if `(s:tack)` is just evaluated once at the beginning of the statement? Or am I way off?

Comment: @BenjaminKovach: I mean if `(s:tack) = stack` is evaluated on every call to `parse'` then it should throw an error if `stack` is empty.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13830/discussion-between-benjamin-kovach-and-kevin-ballard)